# For loop with conditional increment

Tags: ruby, loops

I want a `for` loop that increments according to a condition. The loop should normally increment its index `i` by `1`, but if some condition (`i == 20`) is met, then it should set the value of `i` to `50` (skipping `21`--`49`). Pseudo-code would be something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100;)
  if i == 20
    i = 50
  else
    i = i++
  end 
end
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Ruby does not have a  `:++` method and you don't need the second semicolon in the first line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably one of the few cases where a `while` loop would be appropriate:

```
i = 0
while i < 10
  if i == 2
    i = 5
  else
    i += 1
  end

  p i
end
# 1
# 2
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10
```

Or, you could add your own C-style `for` loop to the language, it's actually pretty simple:

```
class Proc
  def for(iter=->{}, &blk)
    return unless call
    yield
    iter.()
    self.for(iter, &blk)
  end
end

i = 0
-> { i < 10 }.for -> { if i == 2 then i = 5 else i += 1 end } { p i }
# 1
# 2
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10
```

This is equivalent to the following C-style `for` loop (demonstrated in ECMAScript):

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i === 2 ? i = 5 : i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
// 1
// 2
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
// 10
```

Answer (score 2):

As you need to re evaluate the condition based on your incrementing `i` variable, you could use a while statement:

```
i = 0

while i < 100  do
  if i == 20
     i = 50
  else
     i = i+1
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how literal you were trying to be with the numbers there, but here's a more elegant trick just for that:

```
[0...20, 50..100].flat_map(&:to_a).each do |i|
  # ...
end
```

or

```
[*0...20, *50..100].each do |i|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, will add.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this, but it's a way to skip indices when using an enumerator with a block. Suppose

```
skip_index  = 2
skip_number = 4
arr = [*0..10]
```

Then:

```
arr = arr[skip_number..10] if skip_index.zero?
arr.each do |i|
  puts "i=#{i}"
  # do something
  arr.replace([*skip_number..10]) if i == skip_index-1
end
i=0
i=1
i=6
i=7
i=8
i=9
i=10
```

This may provide some insight into how `each` works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is concise while loop that will achieve what you want to do.

```
i = 0
while i < 100
    i == 20 ? i = 50 : i += 1
    p i
end
```

This will return: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
50
51
52
53
...
100